# Looking to filter results on SQL Query to find if Name is in Collections starting with POWER

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, sccm

Working to build a report which shows only names in collections starting with "POWER*"

I have this query that shows all collections Name is in, but only want to return collections I'm looking for.

```
select C.Name0,
       B.CollectionID,
       B.Name
from v_ClientCollectionMembers A,
     v_Collection B,
     v_R_System C
where A.CollectionID = B.CollectionID 
  and A.ResourceID = C.ResourceID 
  and C.Name0 = @Name
```

Comment: Add `and columnname like 'POWER%'` to the where clause,

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo, Hope the below should work for you,

```
select C.Name0,
       B.CollectionID,
       B.Name
from v_ClientCollectionMembers A,
     v_Collection B,
     v_R_System C
where A.CollectionID = B.CollectionID 
  and A.ResourceID = C.ResourceID 
  and C.Name Like @Name
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, The = sign was intentional, it's for Report Builder, to prompt user for input.  essentially, enter your machine name, and see if you're in a specific group or groups.